# Print Message to Gradle Sync log from .gradle script

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to print a more specific message to the Messages console in Android Studio if a gradle sync fails.

Context:

I want to force developers to create a .properties file which my settings.gradle looks for to define a few things. The Messages pane only reads a really generic message, but i want the developer to know this needs to be done.

> Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Any way to achieve this from .gradle ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to force the developer to set your `properties`, you should abort the gradle build with

```
throw new GradleException("your warning message")
```

If you only want to print the warning in concole, [`gradle logger`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html) does support several levels of logging. For example

```
logger.warn('A warning log message.')
```